# I get MySQL shutdown unexpectedly every week, I have to fix this issue for good

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I open XAMPP Control Panel *v3.3.0* and click the start MySQL button and it gives me an error.

Error Log.

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

I tried *Fabrizio Valencia* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61859561/14373656) and the problem was solved well, bad side is I got this error every week that solution is not best practice.
I have to fix this issue for good.

Errors on Windows Event Viewer;

```
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ for information about forcing recovery.

InnoDB: Page [page id: space=0, page number=2] log sequence number 1339427 is in the future! Current system log sequence number 300306.
```

Comment: The database itself seems to be corrupted. Suppressing the error message will not suppress the problem.

Comment: @harrymc What is your suggestion?

Comment: If you restore a copy of the database from a known good backup.  Do you still get the error?  That backup is a required and necessary step to diagnose this issue.  We won't be able to help you without you trying that particular diagnostic.  Multiple error messages indicate the database is corrupted.

Comment: If you don't have a good copy of the database, I suggest creating a new database.

Comment: I'm really confused by what's means the database may be corrupt. it's about MySQL? @harrymc

Comment: MySQL is software for managing databases. I think you need to read more the documentation.

Comment: Yes, its about MySQL.  The message indicates the underlying data has a problem.   If everything is working until it crashes, maybe you can do a database dump, then drop the database and load the new dump.  (Of-course, this assumes the dump file is complete and the dumping process does not cause MySQL to crash)

Comment: Actually I remove XAMPP in my computer. and install a another version, seems like solved.